# Get Snowflake query result in Python

Tags: python, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, directed-acyclic-graphs, snowflake-connector

I am currently working on a POC where we would like to get the snowflake query results into an email using Python.

For example : When executing an Insert statement in Snowflake, I would like to capture the result showing how many records were inserted. Please note that we are using Python Connector for Snowflake to execute our queries from Python script. Also we are using dataframes to store and process data internally.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Snowflake doesnt have any inbuilt notification System, the only way is you must use External Messaging System Like AWS SNS to Send an Email.. But inorder to Know whether the Load is Completed or Not, i think Using the Status of Query_Id helps you, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Following the INSERT statement, you can retrieve the number of rows inserted from `cursor.rowcount`.